# SELECT all date interval from timestamp to timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Is there a way to select all days between two timestamps.

Say I have 2 timestamps 2/1/2015 and 2/28/2015
Is there a way to SELECT all days between the too

Output:

```
days
--------
2/1/2015  |
2/2/2015  |
2/3/2015  |
...
2/26/2015 |
2/27/2015 |
2/28/2015 |
```

Edit:

I am trying to count some records that were created each day between to dates, The table only has a timecreated field with the time stamp of when they were created, what I need to do is generate a table that has all days between 2 dates and a 0 count if no records were created that day or the X for the number of records created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html) to generate all dates between your two dates, and do a join with your table using the timestamp column:

```
SELECT a_date, count(days) FROM 
generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2015-03-31', '1 day') a_date
  left outer join 
    my_table
  on my_table.days = a_date
group by a_date
```

Comment: Thank you generate_series is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Nice!  I havent ever used that before, but it will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  How about:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE days>='2015-02-01' AND days<='2015-02-28'`

Comment: No fair changing the question after I answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table that actually contains the dates, this is one way to do it:

```
--gives a table which contains every date between start & end (inclusive)
declare @startdate datetime = '05/01/2015';
declare @enddate datetime = '05/20/2015';

declare @result table(d datetime);
declare @diff int = datediff(d,@startdate,@enddate);
declare @i int = 0;
while(@i<=@diff) begin
  insert into @result(d) values (@startdate + @i);
  set @i = @i + 1;
end;

select * from @result
```

Comment: Talking about PostgreSQL, not T-SQL :)

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  That explains why the accepted answer didn't actually work when I tried it :).  I'll pay more attention to the tags next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count() on the column indicating that there's a record or not. Say your  column  is called "Record" :

**SELECT count(record) as NbRecord FROM table WHERE days>='2015-02-01' AND days<='2015-02-28'**